# Como se puede saber en que directorio se ejecuta un script de Python?

Tags: python

Quiero saber en que directorio se está ejecutando mi programa principal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aunque ya hay muchas otras preguntas y respuestas sobre este tema, puedes obtenerlo de esta manera.

```
import os
print('getcwd:', os.getcwd())
```

Comment: también funciona en ubuntu

Comment: No se si es una pregunta, pero si funciona